# Extracting JSON in protractor and comparing it with the data send from backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

I am trying to automate my web application whose front end is in angularjs and using protractor. Now  I also want to perform the api testing with protractor only. Like the data send from backend should be same as data received in front end when ajax call is made and JSON is fetched. Not able to find a solution.
Have gone through many links but yet no solution.

[Accessing $http data in Protractor / E2E tests (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359912/accessing-http-data-in-protractor-e2e-tests-angularjs)

Here is what I tried-

```
describe('TestApp',function()
{
    var scope,
            beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller,$httpBackend){
                scope=$rootScope.$new();
                httpBackend=$httpBackend;
                httpBackend.when("POST","path/to/php/ajax.php").respond([{},{},{}]);

            }));
         it("abc",function(){
             httpBackend.flush();
             expect(scope.data.length).toBe(3);
         });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours trying to find a solution to this exact issue. I decided that the best course of action for me was to mock the backend (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend) to intercept the api call. 
Inside the respond I attached a new element to the HTML page. You can then place the JSON within the element and grab the data from the element in your test.

```
$httpBackend.whenPUT(/\/api\/\/.*/).respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.setAttribute('class', 'class-name'); //adds an identifier to more easily grab the data
    var jd = JSON.stringify(data); 
    e.innerHTML = JSON.parse(jd); //Creates a JSON to place in the element, the format of data was not a valid JSON
    $('body').prepend(e); //Adds the element to the start of top of the webpage
    return [200, data, {}];
});
```

In the test, after the call, you can simply grab the element with the data and get the text to test:

```
data = element(by.css('.class-name'));
data.getText().then(function(text){
    expect(text).toMatch(expected, 'Did not match');
});
```

It is not ideal, it is a bit of a work around, but after a long search, it provided the data that I was looking for. I hope this helps you.